# DNS does not work equally on Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, dns

The problem is in browser, ssh,...

**Windows:**

`myservername` is resolved to `myservername.company.com` and both the URLs work fine

**Linux:**

Only `myservername.company.com` works here and `myservername` is not resolved.

Any ideas what might cause this behavior on Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want linux machines to automatically search dns suffixes then your DHCP server will need to issue the "domain-name" option populated with the suffixes you want to be appended to unqualified domain names (where you just state the host part).  The isc-dhcp-server scope directive would be:

```
option domain-name "company.com";
```

It is probable that your windows machines are getting their primary suffix from being a domain member.

If you aren't using dhcp, then you can manually add this to your `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
domain company.com
```

Comment: Also an option for resolv: search company.com  - Will cause the lookup for myservername to first hit myservername.company.com then move on from there to look up names.